# Show clicked item with white background color

Tags: jquery, css

I have a sidebar menu that has some links, also some links also have sublinks.

When some link or sublink of the sidebar is clicked and the url changes to that page I want to add a white background color to that clicked link/sublink. This part is working fine.

But, if it is a sublink besides add the white background I want also that the submenu is visible so that the sublink with the white background is also visible. This part is not working. Do you know how to do that part?

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/s5nb64u2/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-orange">
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Item 0</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Item 1

          </a>
          <ul class="collapse" id="item">
            <li><a href="/item0">Item 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/item1">Item 1.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>

        <li>
          <a href="#item2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Item 2

          </a>
          <ul class="collapse" id="item2">
            <li><a href="/item2">Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/item3">Item 2.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg-orange{
  background-color:orange;
}

ul{
  list-style:none;
}

a.active{
  background-color:white;
}

#sidebar {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: gray;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a{
  background: white;
}
ul ul a {
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background:red;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#sidebar a").each(function() {
  if (this.href == window.location.href) {
    if($(this).parent('li').length == 5){
      $(this).parents('ul.collapse').siblings('a').addClass('active');
    }
    else{
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
$('#sidebar a').each(function() {
  if (this.href == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    let parent = $(this).parent('li').parent('ul');
    if (parent) {
        parent.addClass('show');
    }
  }
});
```

This will look if the parent of the parent is a `ul` and if so, add the `show` class.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matthiastotschnig/es4v7zxu/1/)

*Note:* You should add in your question that you're using bootstrap.